# Extending a positive linear functional on the vector space of ternary quartics to the integral against a Borel probability measure on $x^4+y^4+z^4=1$

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, convex-geometry

Let $T$ be a linear functional on the real vector space $\mathbb{R}[x, y, z]_4$ of ternary quartics (i.e. homogeneous polynomials of degree $4$ in the variables $x$, $y$ and $z$). Suppose that $T(g) > 0$ whenever $0 \neq g \in \mathbb{R}[x,y,z]_4$ is nonnegative on $\mathbb{R}^3$, and that $T(x^4 + y^4 + z^4) = 1$. Does there exist a Borel probability measure $\mu$ on the the hypersurface $X$ defined by $x^4 + y^4 + z^4 = 1$ such that $\int_X g \, \mathrm{d} \mu = T(g)$ whenever $g \in \mathbb{R}[x, y, z]_4$ is a ternary quartic?

Comment: Is $T$ assumed to be positive ($T(g)\ge0$ for any t.q. $g\ge0$ )?

Comment: Good point. I will edit the question.

Comment: Also note that $\mu$ being a *probability* measure implies $T(x^4+y^4+z^4)=\int_X 1 d\mu=1$, which is another necessary condition on $T$.

Comment: If $m$ is any probability measure on $X$ such non-zero elements of $V:=\mathbb{R}[x,y,z]_4$  are not vanishing $m$-a.e. on $X$, we can see $V$ as a (12 dimensional) linear subspace of the real Hilbert space $H:=L^2(X,m)$. So (by Riesz duality thm) any linear functional $T$ on $V$ actually writes as $T(g)=\int_Xgfdm$ for some $f\in V$, thus there is a *signed* Borel measure $\mu<<m$ as required, namely  $d\mu=fdm$.

Comment: What is not clear to me is how to chose $m$ such that $T>0$ implies $f>0$, so that $\mu$ be a positive measure, or equivalently, such that the orthogonal projector $P:H\to V$ maps positive functions to positive polynomials.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken this should be equivalent to the truncated moment problem for (not-necessarily homogeneous) bivariate quartics.  Section 3 of ["Positivity of Riesz Functionals and Solutions of Quadratic and
Quartic Moment Problems" by Fialkow and Nie](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0908.3230.pdf) discusses this case and gives an example of such a linear functional with no representing measure.